# Why doesn't the Linux redirection operator capture the output of my command?

Tags: linux, shell, file, amazon-ec2, command-line

**Context:** I have a program (go-sigma-rule-engine by Markus Kont) on my EC2 instance that runs against a logfile and produces some output to screen.

The command used to run this program is `./gsre/go-sigma-rule-engine run --rules-dir ./gsre/rules/ --sigma-input ./logs/exampleLog.json`

The program produces output of the form:

```
INFO[2021-09-22T21:51:06Z] MATCH at offset 0 : [{[]  Example Activity Found}]   
INFO[2021-09-22T21:51:06Z] All workers exited, waiting on loggers to finish   
INFO[2021-09-22T21:51:06Z] Stats logger done   
INFO[2021-09-22T21:51:06Z] Done
```

**Goal:** I would like to capture this output and store it in a file.

**Attempted Solution:** I used the redirection operator to capture the output like so:
`./gsre/go-sigma-rule-engine run --rules-dir ./gsre/rules/ --sigma-input ./logs/exampleLog.json > output.txt`

**Problem:** The `output.txt` file is empty and didn't capture the output of the command invoking the rule engine.

Comment: could also try `--sigma-stats-format=human --sigma-stats-file output.txt` or `--sigma-emit-file output.txt`

Comment: Yeah, the rule engine comes built in with some nice functionality but I asked this question mainly out of curiosity as to why the file redirection wasn't working.

Comment: @PrithviBoinpally : Perhaps your rule engine does not write to stdout, but either to stderr or directly to the terminal?

Comment: Yep, that was the answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the output you want to capture goes to standard error rather than standard output. Try using `2>` instead of `>` to redirect stderr.

Comment: That did it! Can't believe it was such a simple fix. How does one know where a program directs its output? E.g. how do I know if I program goes to standard error? And is this behavior modifiable?

Comment: This depends on the program's developer decision - a convention is to send the expected program output to stdout and extra information/errors to stderr. for example - `tcpdump` writes the captured packets to `stdout`, but the summary and header to stderr. You can also use the `&>` to redirect both stderr and stdout at the same time. `2>` just means open the target file as fd number 2 (which overrides the default stderr). Either use &> if you don't care to receive both outputs or check using 1>/dev/null if you still receive output on the console (which will be stderr)